# grep and mail the particular error from log if the error count exceed the value

Tags: shell

I need to write a shell script to grep error and write on a file and check the count/no of occurrences of the error. if the count exceed a number then should mail the error with details. so far have written this but not able continue.. please help

```
#!/bin/bash
h1=`hostname`
d1=`date`
XYZLOGS=<dir@ which log located>s
for fname in $XYZLOGS
do
XYZ=$(basename $fname)
f=${fname}/XYZLog.log
var=`tail -5000 $f | grep "Server Error" -C 20`
echo "$var" >/tmp/XYZlogcopy.txt
var1=`tail -5000 $f | grep "Server Error" |wc -l`
if [$var1 -eq "5"] ;
then
if [ ! -z "$var" ] ;
then
echo "$var error on $cbp on server $h1 @ $d1" | mailx -s "error on $xyz" <mail address>
break
else
echo "No matching error found on server $h1 @ $d1" >>/tmp/jobrun.txt
fi
fi
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if [$var1 -eq "5"] ;
```

This means, that you handle ONLY the case, when exactly 5 errors occur.
Try

```
if [$var1 -ge "5"] ;
```

instead.

Use http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html for future reference